# Error, Using deprecated class PySimpleApp after removing EPD

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, wxpython

I am using spyder on Mac OSX 10.8.2 and I had Enthought which I uninstalled. In my code I used pyplot from matplotlib.
However I keep getting the following warning when I run the simple plot program.

```
 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_wx.py:1382: wxPyDeprecationWarning: Using deprecated class PySimpleApp. 
      wxapp = wx.PySimpleApp()
```

I tried pip, manual installing of matplotlib and non of them helped. What should I do about it?
These are my code lines related to plotting:

```
markerSize=400;
fig = plt.gcf()
plt.scatter(X,Y,marker='+',s=markerSize)
circle=plt.Circle((X[i]+k*meshStep,Y[i]+j*meshStep),frequency/magnification,color='r');
fig.gca().add_artist(circle)
plt.xlim(min(X)-1,max(X)+1)
plt.ylim(min(Y)-1,max(Y)+1)
```

Before uninstalling Enthought I didn't have this problem and my figure had zoom and move buttons but right now I only get the graph itself.

Thank you.

Comment: Apparently problem solved. I just deleted any instance of spyder file on pc! Specially the config files in user directory!

Answer (score 11):

You should use `wx.App(False)` instead of `wx.PySimpleApp`. `PySimpleApp` has been deprecated in wxPython 2.9. `wx.App(False)` does basically the same thing.

Comment: Well the problem is I am not using wx.App(False) at all!

Comment: Right, it is matplotlib that is still using wx.PySimpleApp.  The reason you didn't see it with EPD is because they are still using an earlier wxPython 2.8, where wx.PySimpleApp hasn't been deprecated yet.  If you run into this in the future you can work around the problem by creating your own wx.App before matplotlib does.  Depending on how you are using matplotlib you may need to do that in a module that is run before any module that imports matplotlib.